# How to create non equal variables in python

Tags: python

I need to create 3 integers like this:

```
            for i in range(1000):
                 x = random.randint(0, 4)
                 g = random.randint(0, 4)
                 z = random.randint(0, 4)
```

How could I check if x, g, z are not equal
I tried `if x != r and z and g:` but didn't work, it just gives me 3 random integers, So is there sth with my code.

Comment: `x != r and z and g` doesn't mean the same thing as `x != r and x != z and x != g` One way to test if `x,g,z` are all distinct is to test if `len(set([x,y,z])) == 3`

Comment: if ( x != g and x != z and g != z ):

Comment: Right now your code creates random integer 1000 times, 999 of which are not being saved (as the code overwrites the variables `x`, `g` and `z`). Would you like to end up with 3 lists of thousand integers? If not, then what is the 'for loop' for?

Comment: if ( x != g and x != z and g != z ): dosen't work either, gives me same result

Comment: @Rafa, you are right, I thought that would decrease the possibility of getting same number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By far the easiest way to get three distinct randomly chosen integers in the range 0 to 4 is to use:

```
x,y,z = random.sample(range(5),3)
```

Comment: this is what I needed thx, u saved my day